# MYSQL statement works when entered in framework, can't get framework to work with function when saved mysql

Tags: mysql, excel, stored-procedures

History etc:
Project is time sheeet entry, currently works in excel now moving to DB
using excel 2010 as front end for rapid application development.
Framework is SAVETODB
I am not a DB expert, i have known how to write select stmt for years but first time designing complete DB

**Goal: Saving database table changes entered in excel back to mysql** 
using mysql stored procedures (it works when the stored procedures code is saved in savetodb)

Not sure how much help I will get on here for SAVETODB (can't locate a product specific form), I have never used it before but if it works then it is brilliant for my needs.

So in SAVETODB you can enter your update/insert/delete queries or you can point it to your saved procedures in your db (mysql). When I enter my mysql statements into savetodb *i can save to db from excel*, but when saving as procedures in mysql and calling from savetodb *i cannot save to db from excel*.

The reason I say this isn't working is the savetdb "save" button is greyed out when loading second table

Starting out with getting a couple of fields in order to get the statements correct,

**WORKS (ie savetodb allows saving changes) all code in savetodb** - these are savetodb settings (green in linked image)

**Doesn't work, ie using stored procedures** these are savetodb settings (pink in linked image)

**edit 0215** *updated graphic below, savetdb can also accept a base table if referenced as insert/update/delete procedure. this needs the database name prefaced to table, but even with the database name prefaced to the procedure it still doesn't allow saving. maybe i am referencing the procedure wrong ?*

- data from framework file 'savetodb_deb.query_list'
- [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B20N5606_8JfTk9DZjVTVTFDaEE/view?usp=sharing]

The following three do work and update data/perform as expected when run from Navicat

**MYSQL code for insert procedure** - These three are what I am trying to get to work with the second set of savetodb settings

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `NewProc`(IN `id` int,IN `thenumber` char(25),IN `thedate` datetime)
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO time1 
 set Date = thedate, Reference = thenumber;
 END;
```

**MYSQL code for update procedure**

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `NewProc`(IN `idin` int,IN `thenumber` char(25),IN `thedate` datetime)
update `test`.`time1` 
SET 
`Reference` = 'poop', `Date` = '2015-01-15 00:00:00' 
WHERE ID = idin;
```

**MYSQL code for delete procedure**

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `NewProc`(IN `idin` int)
BEGIN
DELETE FROM time1
WHERE
    ID = `idin`;
END;
```

Here is the link to the page at SAVETODB that talks about saving changes 
http://
www.savetodb.com
/help4/configuring-saving-changes.htm

Comment: Not sure why you have to use stored procedures here.  Unless there's some strangeness in SAVETODB that will only allow it to call them you should be able to just issue insert/update/delete statements directly to MySQL.

Comment: Thanks very much for the comment you have pretty much nailed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is actually quite simple within savetodb. Skip all the definer stuff and just enter in the query starting with "Select/insert/update" etc.

Savetodb is an excel add in, they actually create their own db/schema to save all the options so the queries we save as users are simply stored within a table.

to reference excel worksheet cells outside of the data table simply have excel name them (named range) then reference them in your query with : notation.